# How to add a new table in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have a requirement to add a new table in nopCommerce solution.

I am following the article shared at
http://www.lateshtclick.com/blogpost/how-to-add-new-tables-to-nopcommerce
By following the instructions mentioned, I am able to add a new model in `Nop.Admin` project and it works fine.

But when I tried do the same in `Nop.Web` project.  I stuck at Step 5. 
In Step 5 it says, Open this path `~\Nop.Admin\Infrastructure`. Open `AutoMapperConfiguration.cs` class and write below code for Mapping Model to Entity and Entity to Model.

The problem is, I cannot see any file named `AutoMapperConfiguration.cs`. 
How I can have it? Do I have to create a new file or is there any other class where I can map the model to entity and entity to model.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What's the nopcommerce version you're using? Because, The structure usually changes in every major build.

Comment: i have used version nopCommerce 3.90.

Answer (score 0):

The path for files sometimes changes in each nopCommerce new release. But currently the step 5 you mentioned can be found [here](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Areas/Admin/Infrastructure/Mapper). In this case, the file has been renamed to `AdminMapperConfiguration.cs`

```
/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Areas/Admin/Infrastructure/Mapper
```

Comment: i have used version nopCommerce 3.90. My project only that path fall /src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Infrastructure (no find "/Areas/admin/")

Comment: @umair its the Nop.Admin project. The physcially path is src/Administration... Or right click on `Nop.Admin` and select `Open with Folder`

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce 3.9 does not use AutoMapper in Nop.Web.

Preferred way for doing this is using factories and then copy each property.
Just have a look at [nopCommerce/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Factories](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/release-3.90-bug-fixes/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Factories)